# Does foreach use IEnumerator/IEnumerable for built-in types?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, foreach, enumerators

Does the foreach loop use interfaces `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` only for iterating the objects of custom types (classes)  or also for iterating the built-in types (behind the scenes)?

Comment: foreach docs: [MSDN - foreach, in (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foreach doesn't depend on `IEnumerable` as such. However, if a type implements it then a foreach loop will be able to enumerate it (pattern-based matching).

Behind the scenes it only needs a `GetEnumerator()` method and the enumerator must contain `Current` and `MoveNext()`.

From MSDN:

> - The collection type:
>
>   - Must be one of the types: **interface**, **class**, or **struct**.
>   - Must include an instance method named **GetEnumerator** that returns a type, for example, `Enumerator` (explained below).
> - The type `Enumerator` (a class or struct) must contain:
>
>   - A property named **Current** that returns `ItemType` or a type that can be converted to it. The property accessor returns the current element of the collection.
>   - A **bool** method, named **MoveNext**, that increments the item counter and returns **true** if there are more items in the collection.

From [MSDN - Using foreach with Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**UPDATED**: See updated MSDN page for this - [How to: Access a Collection Class with foreach (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9.aspx) .

Comment: Newer MSDN documentation page (for VS 2012 instead of VS.NET 2003): [How to: Access a Collection Class with foreach (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Define enumerator, no IEnumerable declaration.!**

```
public class WorkInfoEnumerator
{
  List<WorkItem > wilist= null;
  int currentIndex = -1;


  public MyClassEnumerator(List<WorkItem > list)
  {
     wilist= list;
  }

  public WorkItem Current
  {
     get
     {
         return wilist[currentIndex];
     }
  }

  public bool MoveNext()
  {
     ++currentIndex;
     if (currentIndex < wilist.Count)
         return true;
     return false;
  }   
}


public class WorkInfo
{
    List<WorkItem > mydata = new List<WorkItem >();
    public WorkInfoEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new WorkInfoEnumerator(mydata);
    }
}
```

**Somewhere in code can use :**

```
WorkInfo wi = new WorkInfo();
foreach(WorkItem witem in wi) 
{  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach uses IEnumerable for both native and custom types.  If you look at System.Array for example, which is the base for all array types, it implements IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

for-each is language construct and does not really differentiate between custom/built-in types.

for each is not dependent on `IEnumerable`, it uses pattern based matching. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx